# encodeURIComponent vs Handlebars.Utils.escapeExpression

Tags: javascript, handlebars.js

Is the latter better in any way than the native function provided in JS? Both seem to work the same way for a string like `test test<img src="#" onmouseover="alert('2');">`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Neither of them is "better" that the other, because they accomplish entirely different tasks.

- `encodeURIComponent()` escapes strings for interpolation into a **URI** (e.g., a querystring variable)
- Handlebars' `escapeExpression()` escapes strings for interpolation into **HTML** (e.g., an element's attribute)

Which one you choose depends on **where your escaped strings goes**, not what your original string contains.

Comment: thanks, so is it right to use escapeExpression() instead of encodeURIComponent() to encode page input values before using them as part of an ajax call?

Comment: @MuKa It depends on how you're doing the AJAX call. Most frameworks will (in the process of serializing the AJAX request body) automatically URI-encode the page's input values.